# Case expression is not working properly in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to concat columns of `supplier` table with comma separator and put it into an alias field named 'contact'. I have used cases for checking null values. Suppose if `contact_number2` is null then `contact_number3` will be in alias field and vice versa. Here is my query

```
SELECT supplier_Name, supplier_Address, supplier_reference, contact_Number1,
       contact_number2, contact_number3,
      (case when contact_number2 is null then contact_number3 
            when contact_number3 is null then contact_number2 
            when contact_number3 is null and contact_number2 is null then 0
         -- when contact_number2 is not null and contact_number3 is not null then  CONCAT(CONCAT(contact_number2,','), contact_number3)
       end) as contact
FROM SUPPLIER
```

If I use the fourth condition then it works but if I use multiple condition then it doesn't work.The error is `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement.

Comment: Great. (A case expression has a return value `then...`. A case statement is conditional execution of code, and can never be a part of a select.)

Comment: If it shows an error, why not share the error message? Also, `concat` accepts multiple inputs, so you only need it once: `CONCAT(contact_number2, ',', contact_number3)`.

Comment: Move the case conditions around, put last first, and do `else coalesce(contact_number2, contact_number3, 0)`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) only accepts 2 parameters in Oracle. As is evidenced by the `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments` you get when you run `select concat('a','b','c') from dual;`

Comment: @Boneist Ah, missed `oracle` tag. Sorry...

Comment: Column data types for contact_number2 and contact_number3?

Comment: You can't concat numbers. First you have to cast them as character. And a case expression's all return types must be type compatible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're after something like this:

```
select supplier_name,
       supplier_address,
       supplier_reference,
       contact_number1,
       contact_number2,
       contact_number3,
       case when contact_number2 is not null and contact_number3 is not null then contact_number2||','||contact_number3
            when contact_number3 is null and contact_number2 is null then '0'
            when contact_number2 is null then to_char(contact_number3)
            when contact_number3 is null then to_char(contact_number2)
       end as contact
from   supplier;
```

Note that case expressions stop at the first condition that is met, so you should make sure that the conditions are in the right order. (Eg. in my query, by the time you get to the "when contact_number2 is null then contact_number3" we already know that contact_number3 can't be null due to the previous condition.)

Also, I have converted your `CONCAT` into the much more common (and more flexible) `||` form. With `CONCAT`, you can only concatenate 2 things at a time, whereas you can have multiple `||`s to join various strings together.

The reason why you got the error you did is because when you concatenate two numbers together (especially when you add a comma into the mix!) the result will be a string. CASE expressions like you to use the same datatype for the result of each condition.

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"        this error is showing up...but if you use only 1st condition without the others then it works

Comment: Ah, right; I've changed the `0` to `'0'` so that it's a string. I see that then contract_numberX columns are numbers, so I have added an explicit `to_char()` around them.

Answer (score 3):

The third case is expecting a VARCHAR and you are providing an INT because of which it is returning an error. Change was that I replaced 0 with '0'. Try this:

```
SELECT supplier_Name,supplier_Address,supplier_reference,contact_Number1,contact_number2, contact_number3,   

  (case 
   when contact_number2 is null then contact_number3 
    when contact_number3 is null then contact_number2 
    when contact_number3 is null and contact_number2 is null then '0'
  when contact_number2 is not null and contact_number3 is not null then  CONCAT(CONCAT(contact_number2,','), contact_number3)
   end)

   as contact
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast numeric data as character before concat.

A case expression's all return values must be type compatible:

```
SELECT supplier_Name, supplier_Address, supplier_reference, contact_Number1,
       contact_number2, contact_number3,
       case when contact_number2 is not null and contact_number3 is not null
                then CONCAT(CONCAT(cast(contact_number2 as varchar(15)),','),
                            cast(contact_number3 as varchar(15)))
            else cast(coalesce(contact_number2, contact_number3, 0) as varchar(15))
       end as contact
FROM SUPPLIER
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
  SELECT supplier_Name, supplier_Address, supplier_reference, contact_Number1,
     contact_number2, contact_number3,
     case when contact_number2 is null then contact_number3 
          when contact_number3 is null then contact_number2 
          when contact_number3 is null and contact_number2 is null then '0'
          when contact_number2 is not null and contact_number3 is not null then contact_number2||','||contact_number3
     end as contact
  FROM SUPPLIER
```

Comment: Re-order. You want 1st and 2nd after 3rd.

Comment: I think this is what OP wants. I just translated `CONCAT(CONCAT(contact_number2,','), contact_number3)` to `contact_number2||','||contact_number3`

Comment: this is showing up                                                                                                      ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"    error

Comment: As explained by @Boneist above, as you are concatenating `comma` in one of case condition, other values should also be `char`. So you need to change 0 to `0`

Comment: @Utsav as the contact_number2/3 columns are numbers, they also need to be converted into strings

Comment: Thanks. I thought oracle will do implicit conversion in this case but I checked just now, it didn't. Will remember it now. Thanks again.